# Show that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x} = 1$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I know that $x-1 < \lfloor x \rfloor \leq x$ hence  $1-\dfrac{1}{x}<\dfrac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x} \leq 1$ for $x>0$. I think it is easy to see from this that the limit should be 1 but I don't know how to formally prove this.

Comment: Do you know the squeeze theorem?

Comment: Comparison of limits.

Comment: Heh, classic case of when not to use L'Hospital.

Comment: Is it me or is not the first time nor the second this exact question have been asked recently?

Comment: Ohh!! My apologizes, I didn't read the $x\to\infty$ part....

Comment: Duplicate: [$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty }\frac {\lfloor x \rfloor}{x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1503018/201168). (*Found using [Approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bx%20%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Clfloor%20x%20%5Crfloor%7D%7Bx%7D%24&p=1)*)

Answer (score 3):

You know that $1-\dfrac{1}{x}<\dfrac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x} \leq 1$ for any $x > 0$ so taking the limits of the leftmost expression and of the rightmost expression you get:

$\lim_{x \to \infty} 1-\dfrac{1}{x} = 1$

and

$\lim_{x \to \infty} 1 = 1$

And since $\dfrac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x}$ is always in between, by the squeeze theorem you get

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} 1-\dfrac{1}{x} \leq \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x} \leq \lim_{x \to \infty} 1 \Rightarrow$$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x} = 1$$

Comment: The $\iff$ is not appropriate