# limit of function: $ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{[x]}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

This is my homework:

> Limit of functions: ($[x]$ is the total part of $x$)
>
> 1. $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{[x]}{x}$
> 2. $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{[x]}{x}$
> 3. $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{[x]}{x}$

For the first one, I used the inequality $$x -1 \leq [x] \leq x.$$
So, $$\frac{1-\frac{1}{x}}{1}=\frac{x-1}{x} \leq \frac{[x]}{x} \leq \frac{x}{x}=1.$$
So my answer is $\displaystyle \lim _{x \to \infty} \frac{[x]}{x} = 1$.
Is that good?
I don't know what to use in other examples$\ldots$

Comment: What is $[x]$? ${}{}$

Comment: I guess it is the floor function.

Comment: the total part from x

Comment: This question was asked a few times before.

Comment: What is $[0.1]$ how about $[-0.1]$?

Comment: As for the question, your solution is fine. Use the same idea for the second limit. As for the third limit here is a hint: what is the value of $[x]$ when $x$ is positive and very close to zero? And what about a negative $x$?

Comment: You can just as easily squeeze your function as $x$ goes to $-\infty$ using the exact same formulation.  As $x$ apporaches $0, \lfloor x\rfloor = 0$ when $x$ is near but greater than $0,$ and $-1$ when it is near but less than $0.$

Comment: if it is near Zero on the right side is [x] = 0 and how on the left is -1?

Comment: A few hints [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2694064/solving-a-sequence-limit-with-floor), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2012704/show-that-lim-limits-x-to-infty-dfrac-lfloor-x-rfloorx-1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1503018/how-to-find-lim-x-to-infty-x-x)

Comment: Thank you for links I know what is [x] but I don't know how to use it in this particular task when x -> 0. This links show $ x-> \ infty $

Comment: For $x \in (-1,1) \setminus \{0\}$ you have ${[x] \over x} = 0$, hence the limit as $x \to 0$ follows... (depending on how you define $[x]$, I am assuming $[x] = 0$ for $|x|<1$).

Comment: @copper.hat: I would assume $[x]=-1$ for $1\le x<0$. Certainly the OP's inequality supports that interpretation.

Comment: [Another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3109974/finding-lim-limits-x-to-0-frac-lfloor-x-rfloorx-and-the-different-def/) related topic.

Comment: It pays to be precise in these matters: although your inequality is correct, it can be improved to $x-1<[x]\le x$.

Answer (score 1):

One way I think about this problem is using a normal identity for floor function and fractional part function  i.e $x = [x]  +   {x}$  using this the 
expression inside the limit can be changed to   $1- (\frac{\{x\}}{x} )$ we know that  $\{x\}$ is lying between $[0,1)$ and $x\to\infty$  hence $\frac{\{x\}}{x} \to 0$ hence the limit is $1$ .  But I recommend that you stick to the sandwich theorem solution as it seems more cool to me.

For the last part  you could start by saying as  x tends to zero we calculate LHL and RHL separately . Now in for LHL the limit is same as the limit of $\frac{1}{x}$ as $x$ tends to zero which  tends to infinity  but the RHL is similar to limit of $\frac{0}{x} =0$ as RHL is not same as LHL hence limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of using $x-1\le\lfloor x\rfloor<x$ (the notation $\lfloor x\rfloor$ instead of $[x]$ is more common nowadays) is good.

For $x>0$ this entails
$$
\frac{x-1}{x}\le\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{x}<1
$$
and for $x<0$ we get instead
$$
\frac{x-1}{x}\ge\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{x}>1
$$
Now squeeze both for $x\to\infty$ (first one) and for $x\to-\infty$ (second one).

Hint for the third limit: if $-1<x<0$, $\lfloor x\rfloor=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite

$$\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{x}=1-\frac{\{x\}}x.$$

As the numerator of the fraction is bounded and the denominator unbounded, the expression tends to $1$ for both $-\infty$ and $\infty$.

For the limit to $0$, notice that $$x<0\implies\lfloor x\rfloor\le-1$$ and the limit on the left cannot exist.